# How can I get the most liked Tweet of a particular day?

Tags: twitter

[Here](https://twitter.com/search?q=min_faves%3A100%20lang%3Aen%20until%3A2010-1-24%20since%3A2010-1-23&src=typed_query) is my example query. It specifies that Tweets must be:

- Written in English
- Tweeted between 23Jan2010 and 24Jan2010
- Have at least 100 "favorites" (likes)

My idea is to use something like the [binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to narrow down the minimum number of likes the Tweet has. Once only one Tweet is returned by a query, I'll know it is the Tweet with the most likes. The problem is, `min_faves`--the value that specifies the minimum number of likes--doesn't seem to work. Look at [this](https://twitter.com/search?q=min_faves%3A100%20lang%3Aen%20until%3A2010-1-24%20since%3A2010-1-23&src=typed_query) query. It specifies `min_faves` as 100. As you can see, [this](https://twitter.com/justinbieber/status/8117934709) Justin Bieber Tweet appears. It has 1.6k likes. [Now, when I attempt to increase the `min_faves` value to 300](https://twitter.com/search?q=min_faves%3A300%20lang%3Aen%20until%3A2010-1-24%20since%3A2010-1-23&src=typed_query) (to narrow down the most liked Tweet), the Justin Bieber Tweet is excluded! I don't know if I am not understanding the query system correctly, or if it is not working, but this seems incorrect. The Justin Bieber Tweet should show up, as it has more than 300 likes. This is just one example of how it doesn't seem to work.

Perhaps this is ocurring because, **within the specified time range**, the Justin Bieber Tweet did not have enough likes to meet the requirements. This would be very good for me, as I am trying to find the most liked Tweet on that particular day, and **not** the Tweet with the most likes *right now* that happens to have been posted on that particular day.

But, I do not believe this is the case. For instance, [this query](https://twitter.com/search?q=min_faves%3A249%20lang%3Aen%20until%3A2009-12-23%20since%3A2009-12-22&src=typed_query) includes 3 Tweets from "Rev Run" when `min_faves` is set to 249, but returns 0 Tweets when `min_faves` is set to 250. I doubt that these Tweets all had exactly 249 likes on that day (as implied by these symptoms).

Does anyone either:

- Understand why these results occur and how I can use this method to find the most liked Tweet of a particular day
- Know of a better, alternative way I can find the most liked Tweet of a particular day

Thank you all

---

@sinanspd requested an example from 2018:

[Here](https://twitter.com/search?q=min_faves%3A300000%20lang%3Aen%20until%3A2018-12-23%20since%3A2018-12-22&src=typed_query) is a search with `min_faves` at 300k. It includes a post with 769k likes and a post with 479k likes. When the query's `min_faves` is bumped up to 400k [neither are returned](https://twitter.com/search?q=min_faves%3A400000%20lang%3Aen%20until%3A2018-12-23%20since%3A2018-12-22&src=typed_query).

Comment: can you try to reproduce this behavior on a tweet post 2018? The way certain metrics got counted changed drastically late 2017 and I believe there are still some inconsistencies between how they are tracked and how they are displayed

Comment: Alright, I added it in.